# Google Sheet Humongous Bottleneck Caused by this FILTER function. How to fix?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have identified by trial and error that this one FILTER function is causing a massive "Calculating Formulas..." delay in my Google Sheet. This is the ONLY cause of the delay I have tested it extensively. MY solution right now is to add a "1" before the equal sign to turn the formula into text so then whenever I need to use the formula to retrieve and save its results I remove the "1" to run it and then put it back and refresh.

Of course this is not a good clean workaround.

Formula is:

```
=FILTER({FORMULARIO!C9:C}, FORMULARIO!J9:J<>"PAGÓ", FORMULARIO!B9:B=10, FORMULARIO!C9:C<>"", FORMULARIO!A9:A>TODAY()-5, NOT(REGEXMATCH(FORMULARIO!Q9:Q, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER(FORMULARIO!Q9:Q, FORMULARIO!J9:J="PAGÓ")))))
```

I'm looking for potential edits to the formula to reduce this humongous delay.
Maybe turn it into a QUERY function?

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, excluding any private or confidential information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This QUERY version of the same FILTER function 100% solved the issue thanks to @player0

```
=QUERY(FORMULARIO!A13:Q, "select C where not upper(J) = 'PAGÓ' and B = 10 and C is not null and A > date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-5, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and not Q matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, QUERY(FORMULARIO!J13:Q, "select Q where upper(J) = 'PAGÓ'", 0))&"'", 0)
```

Comment: Please explain why...

Comment: I dont know why, it simply did,there is something with thtfilter function that doesnt stop calculating formula